# Conditionals and counts in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table
    "ratings", with

```
   an ID column
   a column called like_dislike (holds either null, 0, or 1),
   and a column called lesson_id (a foreign key from lessons).
```

the MySQL table, "lessons", with

```
   an ID column
   a teacher_id column
```

I need to select this information:

```
   "SELECT r.like_dislike FROM ratings r INNER JOIN lessons l on l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id";
```

However, this actually part of a much larger SQL statement, and what I would like to do is:

```
   Foreach lesson_id, if like_dislike == 0, SELECT count(like_dislike) as like
```

AND

```
   Foreach lesson_id, if like_dislike == 1, SELECT count(like_dislike) as dislike
```

I do not know how to turn this pseudo code into SQL. I also need to do this in SQL, rather than in something like PHP, because it is part of a larger SQL statement whose conversion into properly formatted arrays is deeply troubling.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with grouping.  For example:

```
SELECT r.lesson_id, COUNT(*) AS like
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN lessons l ON l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
WHERE r.like_dislike = 0
GROUP BY r.lesson_id;
```

The same for dislike, just change the `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE r.like_dislike = 1
```

**EDIT:**

This can be combined into one query as requested, by adding another level of grouping:

```
SELECT r.lesson_id, r.like_dislike, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN lessons l ON l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
GROUP BY r.lesson_id, r.like_dislike;
```

```
This will give you output, for example:
    +-----------+--------------+-------+
    | lesson_id | like_dislike | count |
    +-----------+--------------+-------+
    |         1 |            0 |    12 |
    |         1 |            1 |     7 |
    |         2 |            0 |     1 |
    |         2 |            1 |     4 |
    +-----------+--------------+-------+
```

so for lesson_id of 1, there are 12 likes, and 7 dislikes, etc...

**EDIT 2:**

To get one row for each lesson_id, you can modify the statement a little:

```
SELECT r.lesson_id,
  CASE WHEN r.like_dislike = 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS like,
  CASE WHEN r.like_dislike = 1 THEN COUNT(*) END AS dislike
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN lessons l ON l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
GROUP BY r.lesson_id, r.like_dislike;
```

For that matter, you don't even need to join on the lessons table at all, unless you are somehow getting ratings that do not link to a lesson.  If you want to include lessons that have no ratings, then you will have to change to an OUTER join:

```
SELECT l.lesson_id,
  CASE WHEN r.like_dislike = 0 THEN COUNT(*) END AS like,
  CASE WHEN r.like_dislike = 1 THEN COUNT(*) END AS dislike
FROM lessons l
LEFT JOIN ratings r ON r.lesson_id = l.lesson_id
GROUP BY l.lesson_id, r.like_dislike;
```

Comment: @compguy24 see my edit for how to combine into a single statement

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a `case` statement, something like this:

```
SELECT r.lesson_id,
       case when r.like_dislike == 0 then (count(*)) end as like,
       case when r.like_dislike == 1 then (count(*)) end as dislike
FROM ratings r INNER JOIN lessons l ON l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
GROUP BY r.lesson_id, r.like_dislike
```

I haven't tested it, but you can see the idea. Further, you must set a `case` to count 1's and another to count 0's because like_dislike can be null.

Comment: I like this better than my answer, it combines both like/dislike into a single row for a lesson_id.  You will need to change the `SELECT r.like_dislike` to `SELECT r.lesson_id`, and also add `GROUP BY r.lesson_id` at the end, otherwise it will not let you use the `COUNT()` aggregate function.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed it, I didn't notice of the error. Nice share

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT if(r.like_dislike =0 ,count(like_dislike) as like , if( r.like_dislike =1 , count(like_dislike) as dislike, 'its null'))
FROM ratings r 
INNER JOIN lessons l on l.lesson_id = r.lesson_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding condition on yr datatable then code it like below:

```
 Declare @Counter int 
 Set @Counter=(SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' FROM tbCourseSemOne 
 where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0)
 if(@Counter <6)
 print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a single stduent'
 else
 print'Insert Code'
```

hope it helps